# How to solve the two dimensional Laplace's equation for certain cases?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Had a doubt regarding Laplace's equation.
In many textbooks, the general solution to the two dimensional Laplace equation is mentioned as:

$$\Phi(\rho,\phi) = A_{0} + B_{0}\ln(\rho) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\rho^n(A_n\cos(n\phi) + B_n \sin(n\phi)) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\rho^{-n}(C_n \cos(n\phi) + D_n \sin(n\phi))$$

in polar coordinates.

For convenience, I will name the two summation terms as:

$$T_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\rho^n(A_n\cos(n\phi) + B_n \sin(n\phi))$$

$$T_2 =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\rho^{-n}(C_n \cos(n\phi) + D_n \sin(n\phi))$$

Not much has really been mentioned on whether these two series, $T_1$ and $T_2$ converge or not. When the solution space does not include either zero or infinity it is generally implicitly assumed that they converge. When the solution space includes the origin, generally the procedure has been to equate the coefficients of the second series, $T_2$, to zero, in other words, to exclude the second series from the solution. 
In many physical problems of interest however, the solution space includes both the origin of the coordinate system and is an unbounded region in all directions. My question is, how can we use the above expansions to handle such cases? Especially when there is a boundary condition of zero (or $ k ln(\rho) $) at infinity. The radius of convergence doesn't seem to be known a priori as the coefficients are unknown. 
For example, if you consider the case of an infinitely long conducting cable of arbitrary but uniform cross-section, (Arbitrary meaning that it need not be something geometrical or symmetric like a circle or a square, and could even be concave; and uniform meaning that the shape and area of the cross-section does not change in the $z$ direction so it can be reduced to a two dimensional problem.) maintained at a constant potential $V$, and where the potential is taken to approach $ k ln(\rho) $ at infinity. It may often be convenient to choose the origin outside the cable. In this case, if I exclude the term $T_2$ (for finiteness at the origin), again the boundary condition $\Phi\to k \ln(\rho)$ as $\rho\to\infty$ will imply that the coefficients in the term $T_1$ become zero as well. So the solution appears to be trivially $\Phi = A_0$ (obviously wrong!) even before I apply the boundary condition $\Phi = V$ at the surface of the cable. 
Can you let me know what I am doing wrong? Can you throw some light on this?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that $V(\rho) = k\ln( \rho)$ implies there is a charge at $\rho=0$. Note that $\frac{dV}{d\rho} = k/\rho$ and this diverges at $\rho = 0$. So, I would not expect $\rho=0$ in the domain of the solution. Of course, $V(\rho) = k\ln(\rho)$ is just the potential for an infinite-line charge. For a charged conductor, the charge is at the surface and since the charge is localized we expect a divergence in the field. Well, I guess generally is just a discontinuity. For example, the infinite conducting charged plane jumps from an E-field zero inside to a finite value outside.

Comment: So, my suspicion is that you should expect non-trivial $T_2$. Also, you can recenter coordinates and do the formula so that $\rho=0$ at some point which was not the original origin, so just because $\rho=0$ is outside the conductor doesn't mean it needs to stay there. If the charge is on some curve which does not enclose the origin then it seems to me that the log term vanishes and you have nontrivial $T_1$ and $T_2$... no fun. So, change coordinates so you can at least capture the asymptotic behaviour by a log. This is my intuition... it could be wrong.

Comment: Why do you say it might be convenient to take the origin outside the cable?  Do you have a specific example?

Comment: @ James S. Cook: Since my origin has been chosen outside the conductor, you would not expect a charge at the origin. So the coefficient of the natural logarithm term would also need to be zero. I have edited my original post to reflect this.

Comment: Perhaps if I state my exact problem I am trying to solve it will make things more clear. The problem is that of an infinitely long hollow conducting cylinderical shell of negligible thickness, maintained at a potential V. However, it is not a complete cylinder but has an infinitely long slit from $\phi=-\alpha$ to $\phi=+\alpha$ where the origin of the coordinate system is taken to be at the centre of the (hollow) incomplete cylinder. To solve this problem it does appear advantageous (at first sight) to take the origin at the center of the hollow incomplete cylinder.

Comment: @ Pragabhava: I have answered your question in the above.

Comment: The main difficulty right now is not that I am not able to solve the problem(Those difficulties would come later.) but that I am facing an apparent inconsistency and am not able to find its root cause. It is not that the boundary conditions are inconsistent as they are very much physically realizable. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that the sum of either series, T1 or T2 can be finite even if their individual terms blow up? If this is the case, then there would be no need to set the coefficients of the terms in these series to zero.

Comment: There is no inconsistency whatsoever. You'll have two solutions, one inside the shell and the other outside. To solve the first one, you'll have to make all coefficients on the singularities zero ($B_0$, $C_n$, and $D_n$), and to solve the second you do the same with the other singularities ($A_n$, $B_n$, not including $A_0$). Then you _glue_ the problem using the bounday and decay condition and that's it. As a consequence, the electric field will be discontinuous in the shell but, hey, we knew that already!

Comment: On a side note, if you loose the spacebar between the "@" and the username, the user is notified that a comment has been made for him/her.

Comment: @Pragabhava: Hi, I have proceeded along those lines and have posted it in the answer below. I am still running into some difficulties. Can you help?                  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HiPragabhava, Thank you for your assistance. If I proceed along those lines, this is what I get:
$$\phi_\text{in} = A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\rho^n\Big(A_n\sin(n\phi) + B_n\cos(n\phi)\Big) $$ for $\rho\leq a$ .
and
$$\phi_\text{out} = A_0 + B_0\ln(\rho) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\rho^{-n}\Big(C_n\sin(n\phi) + D_n\cos(n\phi)\Big) $$ for $\rho>a$ .
Now if I assume symmetry about x axis, the sine terms will vanish. Also, 'glueing' the two solutions will give me:
$$D_n = a^{2n}B_n$$ .
So, now the solutions become :
$$\phi_\text{in} = A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\rho^nB_n\cos(n\phi) $$ for $\rho\leq a$
and
$$\phi_\text{out} = A_0 + B_0\ln(\rho) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\rho^{-n}a^{2n}B_n\cos(n\phi) $$ for $\rho>a$ .
Now, the constants $B_n$ are yet to be determined. Though we don't expect the electric field to be continuous on the (incomplete) cylinder, we would expect it to be continuous on the slit. In other words, the $\rho$ component of the electric field would be continuous at $\rho = a$, $-\alpha<\phi<\alpha$. This means that:
$$ \frac{\partial\phi_\text{in}}{\partial\rho} = \frac{\partial\phi_\text{out}}{\partial\rho}$$ for $\rho = a$, and $-\alpha<\phi<\alpha$.
After differentiation and simplification, this is what I get:
$$ B_0 = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty na^nB_n\cos n\phi $$
for $-\alpha<\phi<\alpha$ .
Since this relation is valid only for the range between $-\alpha$ and $\alpha$ I would not be able to get the coefficients by multiplying both sides by cosines and integrating between 0 to 2$\pi$.  So how to get the coefficients $B_n$ ?
Even if I could get the coefficients something looks fishy here as the L.H.S. is a constant while the R.H.S. depends on the angle $\phi$.
So how can I proceed from here on?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I've been very busy and unable to work on it. As soon as I have time, I'll give it a look.